# Curl Post with multi params

Tags: php, curl

I need to do Post curl in php for this command :

```
curl -k -X POST https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domains/did/applications/test/events 
--user "[UserName]:[Password]" --data "event=restart""
```

that what i try but it's not working :

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domains/did/applications/test/events");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "--user "[UserName]:[Password]" --data "event=restart" ");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

I should get the -K and the -X also, so any ideas how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [curl_setopt](https://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for available options.

```
<?php
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$url = 'https://example.com/';
$cookie = 'cookie.txt';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'event=restart');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful, but i get this error when execute your code The proxy server could not handle the request POST /.
Reason: Error reading from remote server, any ideas please